# About FilesMatch in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I use "FilesMatch" in my .htaccess file, to get "friendly" links. So, I have a file, called rss (no extension), that has some php-code. In .htaccess I have:

```
<FilesMatch "^rss$">
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Now, the hosting company moved the sites to another hosting and the rss file is not executed as php file.

Can you help me to find the problem?
I think it is in php config. But I don't know what is the setting I need to change.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the .htaccess file is still there - it's a hidden file, so may have been missed when moving

Comment: Thanks for answer. I checked. And another settings in .htaccess works well (e.g. DirectoryIndex loader.php  and RewriteRule ... )

Comment: "is not executed as php file." Is php executed at all? Do you see normal output or php code when you run a php page on your browser?

Comment: This imply PHP is running as Apache module. Is it the case? (refer to phpinfo, line *Server API* ; if so, you should read *Apache ... Handler*)

Comment: Php works: PHP Version 5.4.36, and whole site is ok, except rss and adm ! Without adm I can't to enable the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this matters, but the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#forcetype) seems to say that it needs to be in a `<Files>` container. Try using that instead:

```
<Files "rss">
  ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```